# Drupal PHP field stripping HTML tags

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-9

This is **Drupal 9 specific PHP** issue: so bear with me.

I have several fields in Drupal field which are stored as RAW HTML, in Drupal terms which are called - `Fields` and the Values are stored - in field definition `formatted` html.

**Problem :** During re-edit, editor/edit screen pulls stripped html. HTML imported are strpped off HTML tags and HTML classes. And when **re-edited** post is saved the stripped html is getting stored(**Overwritten**)

This is causing serious issues for my site, cause this is a required feature. And some of my website-structue is depends upon the **RAW HTML**.

This could be **PHP** specific issue. If someone has experience regarding this, and how to get away with this - would be a help.

I need to get away with this, this is causing serious troubles with my Website Structure.

**Description :**
Original HTML

```
<ul class="nav flex-column pl-0">

<li class="nav-head">Xamarin</li>

<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Overview</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Analytics</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Snippets</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Flexbox</a></li>

<li class="nav-header">Xamarin Installation</li>

<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Layouts</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Templates</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Themes</a></li>

</ul>
```

When input through `text-formatted-long`
[image: HTML-input]

When imported - During re-edit the formatted-field is striping html tags, and does not pull full html.
[image: imported-stripped-html]

**For post visibility, I have posted the same issue, in several forums. So, this is not spammy qusetion, genuine development question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose `Text format` as `Full HTML`, your HTML will not be stripped anymore.
[image]

#### Update:

It seems that your use of module [Gutenberg](https://www.drupal.org/project/gutenberg) did not display the `Text format` options. So, install the module [Allowed Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats) then enable the format `Full HTML` for your field.

Comment: Let's discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229500/room-for-kien-nguyen-and-munna01)

Comment: Thanks - this worked. Now, full html is pulled by this Module. This could be Drupal 9 specific issue